# Reload DOM element in selenium webdriver after some new tag added

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

In my web page, when I click OK button, some HTML tag will be added in current page source for display popup (the URL is not changed).
How can I get new web element from current page?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to find any new element which was created due to click of OK button? Or do you want to search for a specific element after clicking on OK button?

Comment: I want to search for a specific element after clicking on OK button

Comment: Then @Guy's answer should work for you, if it does not then share the error you get.

Comment: I tried but the exception is "Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element"

Comment: Then please share the html code of that element(check if it is in an iframe tag), and also share the code which you used(the locator)

Comment: The html tag which has been added is div tag

Comment: @Kamal Thanks for your support. The problem is in my html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use explicit wait to wait for the element to be added to the DOM

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("newElementId")));
```